# Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;default;x86_64' in inconsistent location

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

When I run `./gradlew` in my project I got:

```
Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;default;x86_64' in inconsistent location '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/Android-28/default/x86_64' (Expected '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/default/x86_64')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86_64' in inconsistent location '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/Android-28/google_apis/x86_64' (Expected '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;default;x86_64' in inconsistent location '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/Android-28/default/x86_64' (Expected '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/default/x86_64')
Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86_64' in inconsistent location '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/Android-28/google_apis/x86_64' (Expected '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86_64')
```

This is funny because "in inconsistent location":

> '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/Android-28/default/x86_64'

and "expected":

> '/Users/aero/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/default/x86_64'

are the same location!

What can I do to fix this error?!

Answer (score -1):

Change the folder's name android for Android